# Losing logs with Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'm using Logstash in the typical multiple Logstash Shippers -> Logstash Indexer -> Elastic Search. I've been doing tests that involve shutting down the Indexer for a few minutes and starting it up again, and have noticed that the logs from about 30 second - 2 minutes after shutting down the Indexer are not received when the Indexer is turned back on. All the other logs are received.

My hunch is that that the Indexer is keeping its TCP socket open for longer then it is actually reading events, but I'm not sure. Has anyone experienced something like this before, or has an idea of how to investigate it?

**EDIT 1:**

I set up a test locally where one shipper was sending to one receiver/indexer. Shutting down the receiver triggers a 'connection refused' error on the shipper side, and then it sleeps until it detects the receiver come back up. However, 3 seconds of logs were sent but not received, so same problem as in my staging environment but a smaller interval.

Comment: "shutting down" how?

Comment: sudo service logstash stop

Comment: Logstash has an internal pipeline, but I would expect it to be flushed (provided a graceful shutdown like you're doing and the availability of all outputs).  Logstash2 is supposed to make the internal pipeline more resilient.